# How do you iterate over each row in a data frame without applying each index to every row?

Tags: python, loops, pandas

How do you iterate over each row in a data frame without applying each index to every row?

```
>>> d2 = {'one' : pd.Series(['us 1','uk 2','china 3','india 4'], index=['a', 'b', 'c','d'])}
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
>>> df2
one
a   us 1
b   uk 2
c   china 3
d   india 4

>>> for index, row in df2.iterrows():
>>>    for line in df2['one']:
>>>        print index, line
a us 1
a uk 2
a china 3
a india 4
b us 1
b uk 2
b china 3
b india 4
c us 1
c uk 2
c china 3
c india 4
d us 1
d uk 2
d china 3
d india 4
```

I want to be able to modify each row in column one, and to do that, I believe I need the line: `for line in df2['one']:`

But, as you can see, when I write this line, index a loops over the whole data frame and so on down to index d.

Is there a way that I can loop so that I can modify what I need to in each row but maintain the initial integrity of the data frame which is one row for each index, for rows total?

Comment: Inline code is added by surrounding with backticks (e.g. \`code\` will render as `code`), while indented code blocks are done by indenting each line with 4-spaces.  Additionally, the standard syntax for python input/output (resembling an interactive session), if using `>>>` for input.  You can click the grey `edit` button to see how I've reformatted your text for future reference.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You are not asking what your real problem is, you want advice on your method of solving it. Which is bad, and is called the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Read it, and avoid it next time. Loops are very slow, and rarely needed with packages like Pandas. What you really want done might be accomplished without any loop. But you cannot be helped unless you ask your question correctly. (That's why no one replied to you, even though 14 hours have elapsed since you asked.)

Comment: Thank you, Kartik, for explaining this to me. I'll make a new post with my question in it.

Comment: Here's my new post. Thanks for helping me. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34121379/how-do-i-make-new-columns-in-data-frame-from-split-string-in-a-row-of-a-differen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kartik mentioned, best practices is avoiding loop.

But it is possible loop this way:

```
for line in df2['one']: 
    print line

us 1
uk 2
china 3
india 4
```

But if you want extract data from column `one`, pandas docs describes this splitting [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings):

```
import pandas as pd

d2 = {'one' : pd.Series(['us 1','uk 2','china 3','india 4'], index=['a', 'b', 'c','d'])}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
print df2

df2['two'] = df2['one'].str.split(' ').str[0]
df2['three'] = df2['one'].str.split(' ').str[1]
print df2

#       one    two three
#a     us 1     us     1
#b     uk 2     uk     2
#c  china 3  china     3
#d  india 4  india     4
```

Comment: Thank you, Jezrael. Here's a new [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34121379/how-do-i-make-new-columns-in-data-frame-from-split-string-in-a-row-of-a-differen) that asks my question more clearly, I hope.